# How to insert an image with width of double column between title and abstract in IEEEtran document

Tags: graphics, floats, titles, ieeetran

I am using the `IEEEtran` class. I tried the following code for inserting an image between the title and the abstract. However, texts are on top of the inserted image. How can I avoid that?
[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{here title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{While solid paints (left top).}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{center}

\begin{abstract}
here abstract.
\end{abstract}

\blindtext\\
\blindtext\\
\blindtext\\
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to consider first if it is really a good idea to have an image just after the title before the abstract. This is very unusually and might be criticized by the reviewers or confuse the readers.

Nevertheless, here a technical solution. As `figure*` does not work here as it is placed on the second page, independent what settings I used, and a second `\twocolumn` command (the first one is inside `\maketitle`) has the same behavior, I decided that the image must be placed as part of the title code, i.e. inside `\maketitle`. The easiest way is to redefine the `\twcocolumn` macro (which sets content over two columns) so that your code is inserted after the title code of the class.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{here title}

\let\oldtwocolumn\twocolumn
\renewcommand\twocolumn[1][]{%
    \oldtwocolumn[{#1}{
    \begin{center}
           \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
           \captionof{figure}{While solid paints (left top).}
           \label{fig:fig1}
        \end{center}
    }]
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
here abstract.
\end{abstract}

\blindtext\\
\blindtext\\
\blindtext\\
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]